# Show that if $r$ is an nth root of $1$ and $r\ne1$, then $1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1} = 0$.

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, power-series

Show that if $r$ is an nth root of $1$ and $r\ne1$, then $1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1} = 0$.

I think I can represent all the roots of 1 as follows:

$r = 1^{\frac{1}{n}} ( \frac{\cos{2\pi k}}{n} +  i\frac{\sin{2\pi k}}{n} )$

From there I am not sure how to get to $1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1} = 0$.

Comment: You need $r \neq 1$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ... + r^{n-1}$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series.  The formula for this summation, as long as $r \ne 1$, is

$$\frac{r^n - 1}{r - 1}$$

Since $r$ is an nth root of unity, $r^n - 1 = 0$.  Since the denominator is nonzero, this quantity is equal to zero.

Hope this helps!

Comment: would each $r$ represent a de Moivre number (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)

Comment: @TedFlethuseo- All those powers of $r$ are roots of unity, since if you raise them to the $n$th power you'll get back 1.

Comment: I think there might be an error here: it should be (1-r^n)/(1-r)

Comment: @TedFlethuseo- That fraction is the same.  Just multiply the top and bottom by -1.

Answer (score 14):

Multiply top and bottom by $(1-r)$.

$$1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1}=\frac{(1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1})(1-r)}{(1-r)}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=\frac{0}{1-r}=0$$

Note: $r\neq 1$ is necessary, else the statement is false.

Comment: Do you mean this: $(1-r)/(1-r)(1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1} = 0)$

Comment: So this statement is true for all the roots of 1, except for the root that is 1 itself.

Comment: Correct, so long as $r\neq 1$, the sum is zero.  If $r=1$, the sum is $n$.

Comment: Wouldn't I arrive to the same conclusion if I consider that a(1-r^n)/(1-r) is the sum of the first n terms of a geometric series. and in the series I have a = 1. I mean I woudn't have to multiply top and bottom by (1-r).

Comment: You still have $1-r$ in the denominator, so you get the same conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

We know that $r^n - 1 = 0$ but we can factorise the LHS as $(r-1)(r^{n-1}+r^{n-2}+...+r+1)=0$.

However $r\neq 1$ so the other bracket must be $0$.

Answer (score 7):

Just multiply your sum by $r$.  You get the same thing you started with. Since $r \neq 1$, this is only possible if your sum is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the equation $r^{n}=1$ has $n$ roots in the complex plane (because $r^n$-1 is an nth degree polynomial).  You know one of the roots is 1, so the polynomial $r-1$ must be a factor of this nth degree polynomial.  Now what happens if you divide by $r-1$ (Assuming $r \neq 1$)?

$\frac{r^{n}-1}{r-1}=1+r+r^2+...+r^{n-1}$ by long division.

So this is a true equation for $r \neq 1$, and the left-hand-side will be 0 for any other root of unity.

Comment: You remove that factor, I think.. so I'm guessing you cant have r = 1 because you removed the 1-r.. I'm still confused, trying to put this together

Comment: You are right, you cannot have r = 1, BUT since 1 is a root of the polynomial $r^n-1$, (r-1) is part of the factorization of $r^n-1$, and thus can be divided by it, in the same way that (x-2) is a factor of $x^2-5x+6$ and if we divided by (x-2), we would end up with the remaining factors, in this case (x-3).

Comment: I am guessing that only the imaginary roots of 1 satisfy  $1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1} = 0$, because 1 would be the only real root.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the roots of any polynomial $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$ is $-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}$. In the case of the polynomial $x^{n}-1$ this expression is zero.

As Carsten Schultz points out, this argument only proves the case when $r$ is a *primitive* $n^{th}$ root of unity. This does not exclude any cases, though, as every root of unity is primitive for some $n$.  It is also important to see that this excludes the case of $r=1$, since then $-a_{n-1}/a_{n}$ is non-zero.

Comment: This only shows the claim if $r$ is a primitive root of unity so that $r^k$ gives all roots.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand - in this case $-a_{n-1}/a_{n}=1+r+r^{2}\ldots$ identically.

Comment: Your argument shows that the sum of all roots is zero, e.g. for $n=4$ it would show that $1+i+(-1)+(-i)=0$. Now indeed that is $1+r^1+r^2+r^3$ for $r=i$ or $1+r^3+r^2+r$ for $r=-i$. However, for $r=-1$ one would like to show that $1+(-1)+1+(-1)=0$, and I do not see how that follows. (Except, of course, by considering $n=2$ instead.)
Did I misunderstand your argument?

Comment: Ah I see your point! It is the case that any root of unity is primitive for *some* $n$, though, so we still have the full theorem. I'll add a note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has posted this - geometrically the roots of unity point to edges of a regular polygon from centre (0,0). Clearly by symmetry, they must vectorially add to zero.